# React useEffect Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I always get this problem when using useEffect but I see others do it just fine. Here is my Code.
Component 1 (Parent):

```
 const UsePrevious = (value)=> {
    const ref = useRef(0);
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(value)
      ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
  }

  const FetchAndHighlight = (index) => {
    const prevAmount = UsePrevious(index);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(prevAmount !== index) {
          getNote(props.data.company_id)
          .then(data=>{ 
           return setNotes(data)
          })
          .catch(err=>console.error(err))
        }
    }, [index])
```

Component 2 (child)

```
function handleDelete (row){
  console.log(filteredItems)
  const index = filteredItems.findIndex(r=>r._id===row);
  props.FetchAndHighlight(index);
  deleteNote(row)
  console.log(row)
toast.info('Note deleted sucessfully.')
if(props.combined === 0){props.setCombined(1)} else{props.setCombined(0)}
}
```

Comment: May be you have problem with name. Try to rename `FetchAndHighlight` to `useFetchAndHighlight`

Comment: Nah didnt do anything...Any other suggestions?

Comment: Is `handleDelete` callback that you put to onChange or onClick?

Comment: You are passing hooks as a prop, thats **NOT** how it works, you don't pass hooks as regular functions, please read about Rules Of Hooks in docs

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass hooks through props and more importantly, [you must use hooks on top level](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) and not in functions like `handleDelete` instead import the hook and use it:

```
// export
export const useFetchAndHighlight = (index) => {...}

// usage
import { useFetchAndHighlight } from './useFetchAndHighlight.js';

// Don't use inside function
useFetchAndHighlight(index);
```